# Update Redux and Pull Info on New Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm pretty new to redux and would like to know how i can update my redux store so that if a user performs an action to update the database that i can write a function that will update the redux store.

whats the best way to go about this?

After the user updates the db i'm calling .then() to update redux store (which calls to the DB to get the new info)

when i navigate to the new screen, the data from redux is still the same

Comment: Can you share some code please?

Answer (score 0):

1. When the user updates the database, how to receive the value as the return value of the API or a local value to the **dispatch** it to redux reducer.
2. How to use ***redux-saga*** to continuously dispatch a return value of the API or a local value to redux whenever the user updates or accesses the database.

You can use general redux or redux-toolkit.

I hope it helps you.